# How do you check for same domain iframe loading errors?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Let us say you have a simple HTMLIFrameElement.  You are on stackoverflow.com and so is the iframe `src`.

Is there any way to prepare the iframe element so that when I set the `src` property, I can detect loading errors?  This particular iframe is shown in the future, so it is possible that the application can load, but show a 404 on this element (if they lost connection for example).  I need a way to deal with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could set the src via ajax, there you get the info if the site could have been loaded.

Other way:
If the src is the same origin, and if you can edit the 404 page you could paste a small unique code within this 404 page and search for it within the iframe, so you know that the site couldn't be found.

```
$('#iframe').load(function () {
     var errorCode = $("#iframe").find('#unique-error-code').text();
    if ( errorCode.indexOf("my errorcode") >= 0 ) {
        // error
    } else {
        // success
    }
});
```